# How to assemble for an ARM11 core

Tags: assembly, arm

I have got a S3C6410 board. S3C6410 has a ARM1176JZF-S core.
I tried to compile a demo project for this IC using IAR v6.4?.
There is an assembly file in the project containing the following code:

```
IMPORT      _main                    ; C entrypoint for Steppingstone loader.
AREA |C$$code|, CODE, READONLY
global      Start

Start
    b        _main

    DCB     "ABCDabcd"
    END
```

When compiling the project I get BAD INSTRUCTION error for line 2 and 3. Do you have any idea how I can compile this file? Thanks

Comment: Put spaces before the IMPORT and AREA directives.

Comment: The title is misleading. This has nothing to do with the target processor and everything to do with the toolchain used. Is IAR 6.4 a supported toolchain for this example? If not, suggest rewording question to enquire about the methods required for converting from RVCT to IAR directive syntax.